# Value of bindings in SML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, ml

can someone please explain why is "ans" is bound to value of 16 in here after evaluation - this is a correct answer?

I thought the answer 3 since we're calling function f and sending values 1 and 2 as function f doesn't also see the values 5 and 10 but I guess I am wrong.

```
val x = 1

val y = 2

val f = fn y => x + y

val x = 5

val y = 10

val ans = f x + y
```

Comment: Judging by your recent questions on StackOverflow, have you considered reading a textbook on Standard ML? Shadowing of value bindings (rather than calling them variables) would be one of those non-obvious things that are still systematically covered in any decent textbook. You could consider [ML for the Working Programmer](https://www.amazon.co.uk/ML-Working-Programmer-Larry-Paulson/dp/052156543X).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is sometimes called **lexical scoping**. The function `f` was defined in the scope of a certain binding for `x`, that scope is the only scope that matters in understanding what `f` does when `f` is invoked. The fact that `x` has a different meaning in the scope in which `f` is invoked doesn't affect the meaning of `f` itself. In the context of functional programming anything else would violate [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency). In the scope of a binding such as

```
val x = 1
```

it should be possible to freely replace `x` by `1`. Thus your definition of `f` should be *equivalent* to the definition:

```
def f y = 1 + y
```

as, indeed, it is.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out. Here goes:

The function `f` doesn't get evaluated until the end. So at:

```ml
val ans = f x + y
```

... the function `f` gets called with the recent value `x` which is `5` because the value of the previous `x` is being shadowed. So at:

```ml
val f = fn y => x + y
```

... the value received becomes the value of `y`. and here the function `f` takes the value the previous `x` which is `1` so that's a total of `6` (`x` comes from static environment). Then:

```ml
val ans = f x + y
```

we get back here: `6 + 10 = 16`